# while loop running every X minutes in JS

Tags: javascript

```
function test(){
  localStorage.setItem('run', "true");
  var loop = 2;
  while (loop > 1) {
    var run = localStorage.getItem('run');
    if (run === "true") {
        //HELP!
        //How can I make this while loop call getData() function every 5 minutes
        getData()
    }else {
        var loop = 0;
    }
  }
  console.log("Completed")
}


      function getData(){
        //requesting data etc
        if (data === "abc"){
          localStorage.removeItem('run');
          localStorage.setItem('run', "false");
        }
       return;
      }
```

How can I make the while loop call getData() function every 5 mins. With current code its hammering the API being called at getData(). I want it to chill down and take it easy ;)

Comment: Are you just looking for the `setInterval` function?

Comment: @David Yes I guess but I am not sure where to add it.. Inside the while loop itself or inside getData()

Comment: Honestly it's not obvious to me what the loop is even trying to achieve.  `setInterval` simply executes a function over and over at a given interval.  (In this case 5 minutes.)  You'd call it wherever/whenever you want to start the interval.  And then use `clearInterval` to stop it.  (Or you can wrap the logic within that function in an `if` condition if you want to keep the interval going but only conditionally perform the operation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `while` loop with `setInterval`:

```
function test(){
  localStorage.setItem('run', "true");
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    var run = localStorage.getItem('run');
    if (run === "true") {
      getData()
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log("Completed")
    }
  }, 300000);
}

function getData(){
  //requesting data etc
  if (data === "abc"){
    localStorage.removeItem('run');
    localStorage.setItem('run', "false");
  }
}
```

`setInterval` works like an infinite loop with a delay. `clearInterval` stops the infinite loop.

Example with 1 second delay:

```js
let localStorageRun;
let data = 0;

function test() {
  localStorageRun = "true";
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    var run = localStorageRun;
    if (run === "true") {
      getData()
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log("Completed")
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function getData() {
  ++data;
  console.log('getData', data);
  if (data === 5) {
    localStorageRun = "false";
  }
}

test();
```